# Sass Imports conflicting, BootStrap5 ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: css, sass, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-5

I am starting to use Scss for Bootstraps 5 and I am encountering an issue (at least a new one) that I cannot solve or find any answers on the internet.

I have recently made a Sass file and have gotten it to compile and register changes when using bootstrap classes. This worked when my import declarations were:

```
@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss";
@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss";
@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/_mixinx.scss";
```

These 3 import statements were working fine and I was able to adjust position values, colors using map-merge and custom variables.

Now, I tried adding a custom utility (to adjust the width. (I worked with tutorials, forums etc for all of these suggestions/methods) and when I did the mapping and import for the utilities.scss everything ceases functionality. None of my other mappings work. I have tried reorganizing some of the import statements, and there does not seem to be a resource for my particular question/situation.

Here is my sass file code:

```
// Variable overrides Below Here

$BethanyGreen: #8eacac;
$Test: #2a609c;


// Variable overrides Above here
// Import function and variables

@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss";
@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss";
@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss";
@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/_utilities.scss";
@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/_helpers.scss";
@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/utilities/_api.scss";

// Variable Mapping Below Here

$Custom-Position-Values: ( 5: 5%, 10: 10%, 15: 15%, 20: 20%, 25: 25%, 30: 30%, 35: 35%, 40: 45% );

$position-values: map-merge($position-values, $Custom-Position-Values);

$Custom-Colors: ( "BethanyGreen": $BethanyGreen, "Test": $Test );

$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $Custom-Colors);
$theme-colors-rgb: map-loop($theme-colors, to-rgb, "$value");
$utilities-colors: map-merge($utilities-colors, $theme-colors-rgb);
$utilities-text-colors: map-loop($utilities-colors, rgba-css-var, "$key", "text");
$utilities-bg-colors: map-loop($utilities-colors, rgba-css-var, "$key", "bg");


$Custom-Width-Util: ( 10: 10%, 15: 15%, 20: 20%, 30: 30%, 40: 40%, 45: 45%, 60: 60% );

$utilities: map-merge($utilities,("width": map-merge(map-get($utilities, "width"), (values: $Custom-Width-Util))));

//Variable Mapping Above Here

//Import Bootstrap
@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

Things I have tried:

1. Comment out all the new code and import statements. Once removed the code worked fine as before, so it has to do with the _utilities.scss or positioning.
2. Organized import statements. Tried placing the _utilities.scss import in a different order, first, last, between etc. it does not work.

Furthermore, at one point the custom map-merge with $utilities was working, just none of the color components. Now that I have tinkered with things, none of it works. Any help is appreciated and thank you in advanced for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I ended up figuring this out by commenting out code, moving it on the document and recompiling. Eventually I got to the point where I moved removed the _helpers.scss and _api.scss imports, and placed the import below the previously functioning code. This seems to work and has restored functionality to my custom sass file

```
$BethanyGreen: #8eacac;
$Test: #2a609c;


// Variable overrides Above here
// Import function and variables

@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss";
@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss";
@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss";


// Variable Mapping Below Here

$Custom-Position-Values: ( 5: 5%, 10: 10%, 15: 15%, 20: 20%, 25: 25%, 30: 30%, 35: 35%, 40: 45% );

$position-values: map-merge($position-values, $Custom-Position-Values);

$Custom-Colors: ( "BethanyGreen": $BethanyGreen, "Test": $Test );

$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $Custom-Colors);
$theme-colors-rgb: map-loop($theme-colors, to-rgb, "$value");
$utilities-colors: map-merge($utilities-colors, $theme-colors-rgb);
$utilities-text-colors: map-loop($utilities-colors, rgba-css-var, "$key", "text");
$utilities-bg-colors: map-loop($utilities-colors, rgba-css-var, "$key", "bg");

@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/_utilities.scss"; // moved this import statment from the cluster above
//Variable Mapping Above Here
$Custom-Width-Util: (5: 5%, 7: 7%, 10: 10%, 15: 15%, 20: 20%, 30: 30%, 40: 40%, 45: 45%, 60: 60% );
$Custom-Height-Util: (5: 5%, 7: 7%, 10: 10%, 15: 15%, 20: 20%, 30: 30%, 40: 40%, 45: 45%, 60: 60% );

$utilities: map-merge($utilities,("width": map-merge(map-get($utilities, "width"), (values: $Custom-Width-Util))));
$utilities: map-merge($utilities,("height": map-merge(map-get($utilities, "height"), (values: $Custom-Height-Util))));

//Import Bootstrap
@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

Not what I figured would be the solution, but hopefully this helps if anyone is encountering similar issues.